# While Loop isnt breaking

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

when i run the program it loops over and over even if `game rounds` is equal to `rounds` tried different ways but still bugging or theres just something i cant see

heres the code:

````
print('Rock Paper Scissors!\n"r" for rock, "p" for paper, "s" for scissors\n')
rounds = int(input('How many rounds?: '))
game_round = 0
game = game_round != rounds
while game:
    user = input('\nRock, Paper, Scissors?: ').lower()
    computer = random.choice(['r', 'p', 's'])
    print(f'Computer: {computer}\n')
    player = user
    opponent = computer
    user_win = 0

    # r > s, s > p, p > r
    # if player wins:
    player_win = (player == 'r' and opponent == 's') or (player == 's' and opponent == 'p') or (player == 'p' and opponent == 'r')
    # if computer wins:
    computer_w = (opponent == 'r' and player == 's') or (opponent == 's' and player == 'p') or (opponent == 'p' and player == 'r')

    if user == computer and game:
        game_round = game_round + 1
        print('Tie!')

    if player_win and game:
        user_win = user_win + 1
        game_round = game_round + 1
        print('You win!')

    if computer_w and game:
        game_round = game_round + 1
        print('You loose!')

    if game is False:
        print(f'Score {user_win}/{rounds}')```
````

Comment: where do you assign `false`  to `game`?

Comment: The `game` variable is pointless, just set while loop to the condtion `while game_round != round`

Answer (score 0):

As Sayse says in the comment, you can do like this:

```
user_win = 0 # <- put user_win outside the loop so you can access it outside the loop.

while game_round != round:
   # other code

print(f"Score {user_win}/{rounds}")
```